# How encapsulation works in Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, encapsulation

Say I have two classes `ListNode` and `List`.

```
public class List{
    private ListNode head;
    public List(){head = null;}
    public void insertFront (int obj)
    {
        head = new ListNode(obj, head);
    }
    // other methods to be declared
    public boolean isEmpty(){...}
    public Object removeFront() {...}
    public Object removeBack(){...}
    public void insertBack(Object value){...}
    public ListNode nth(int i){...}
    public void insertAfter(ListNode node, Object value){...}
}  

public class ListNode{
    public Object item;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(Object value,ListNode next){
        this.item = value;
        this.next=next;
    }
    public ListNode(Object value){
        this(value,null);
    }
}
```

In a video I was looking at, it said that no method of `List` returns a `ListNode`, therefore individual nodes cannot be tampered with. An external class can't get its hands on references to `Node` on the list.
Does that mean once I create a list as

```
List list=new List();
list.insertFront("a");
list.insertFront("b");
list.insertFront("c");
```

**This particular list** can't be changed by an outside class. But still an outside class has the ability to create a separate linked list?

```
public class A{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        ListNode list=new ListNode("a");
        System.out.println(list.item);  
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can access an item created in class `List` while being on class A?
Can someone please explain how encapsulation works as I am new to Java and programming and I am still trying to understand the concept of encapsulation.

Comment: For example, to make nodes strictly encapsulated, you need to convert `node.value` & `node.next` to `node.getValue()` & `node.getNext()` and make sure that `getValue()` doesn't return a reference to the inner `this.value` object

Comment: The answers haven't solve my problems i understanding what it means by  A particular list that is created  can't be changed by an outside class. But still an outside class has the ability to create a separate linked list?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating two different classes, you can define ListNode class inside the List class. This way you will be hiding the internal representation of using a ListNode class.

Also, the basic API supported by a linked list is

> public void addItem(int val);
>
> public void removeItem(int val)
>
> public int size()

list.insertFront() can be easily implemented in the list class. The list class will have a field "head" which will be the head of the linked list. So to insert a node at the front of the linked list, all you have to do is to change the head of the linked list. And now there is no need to pass back the head reference to the calling class.

removeFront, removeBack, etc can be similarly implemented.

However, you will have to change the API and the implementations if you want to remove a specific node in the linked list. ie, we have not added the functionality of removing a specific node from the linked list. The current remove method takes as argument an int value and not an object of the Node class.

You can find an implementation of a doubly linked list class in Java [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/DoublyLinkedList.java.html). I find this implementation reliable as this implementation is taught by professors from Princeton University.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about access modifiers in Java for a bit before you try to understand encapsulation using java.

If you mark your variables as public, you can always access any objects. However it is a bad practice.Your objects should always be private or protected.

Since you marked the element ListNode as private , you cannot access it from anywhere except within the ListNode class/object, unless you have a leaking function which  returns that reference (which is bad code)

For Ex: 
public class List{
    private ListNode internalListNode;
    ....
    public ListNode badLeakyRef(){
      return internalListNode;
    }
}